# Email Daily Maintenance Plan Report

Tags: sql-server, maintenance

Im currently running a Maintenance Plan on SQL Server that does the following:

- 1 daily full backup
- Hourly transaction log backup
- 1 daily maintenance cleanup

On the reporting options I have it set up to send a report to an email recipient, so now I'm getting an email hourly.

Is it possible to receive a summary email, for example at the end of the day with results of all the sub plans? Any suggestion on how to accomplish something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start from this sql server central article: [Automating SQL Server Health Check](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Automating+SQL+Server+Health+Checks/68910/) (Subscription required). The script will send you email which contains a summary of your jobs, disk space etc. You can create a job that run the stored procedure and schedule it to run once a day so that you will get the report in your inbox.